# Sprite Game - Number of nodes (iPhone)

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I was wondering if there was a simple way to determine the number of nodes in a given view, I have found the:

```
NSArray *array = [self nodesAtLocation:CGPoint];
```

But would rather not do this for every point on the screen, I cannot find a simple way to determine this (Although I believe it is counted as I can see the number of nodes on the screen!)

EDIT: I found this solution you can use the

```
[self children].count
```

function which will return the current number nodes on the screen from this scene.

Comment: You can put your edit as an answer and accept it. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
[self children].count;
```

To pass as an integer, this should work:

```
int numberOfNodes = (int)[self children].count;
```